# How to use reserved words in SQL query?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have tried several ideas using prepared statement, but none of them worked. These are:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO APP.TEST (Name, 'role') VALUES (?, ?)";

String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO APP.TEST (Name, [role]) VALUES (?, ?)";

String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO APP.TEST (Name, role) VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Comment: What do you mean "none of them worked"?  What happened?

Comment: use `role` , it should work. It seems overstackflow remove the chars.

Comment: I tried that as well

Comment: Derby docs specify double quotes for identifiers. http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/crefsqlj1003454.html

Comment: But `role` is not on the [list of reserved words](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html)

Comment: The problem is that role is a SQL reserved word

Comment: @Samir you mean `\`role\`` (backslash-escape the backtick character) - that's MySQL's method.

Comment: @user1036645 You tagged this with `derby` but `role` is not on Derby's list of reserved words. Are you actually using Derby, or a different RBDMS?

Comment: Yes you are right. How did you add ?  @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Yes I am using Derby. In this implementation role is a reserved word.

Comment: Should be double quotes then, as `"role"`.

Comment: @Samir The outer string is backtick-quoted as inline code. Within that, backslash-escape the backticks: \`\\`word\\`\`

Comment: The use of double quote causes compiler error. Because it expects a variable

Comment: I just gave you plus 1 reputation. But I don't know who rate me down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache Derby's documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.7/ref/crefsqlj1003454.html) specifies that delimited SQL identifiers may be double-quoted. So your SQL string would eventually look like:

```
INSERT INTO APP.TEST (Name, "role") VALUES (?, ?)
```

Since that is being placed inside a string already double-quoted, backslash-escape the inner quotes:

```
String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO APP.TEST (Name, \"role\") VALUES (?, ?)";
```

Derby's [list of reserved words](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefkeywords29722.html) does not currently specify `role` as reserved, but if in your implementation it does appear to be reserved, you must quote it accordingly.

Comment: I encountered another issue, which is SQL name conflict with the table name. I tried String insertSQL = "INSERT INTO DATABASE.\"User\" (Name, username, password, \"role\") "
                     + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"; but it did not work.

Comment: Quote both parts I suppose, like `\"DATABASE\".\"User\"` -- that's how the documentation example looks.